# what does the plus sign mean in return redirect('/details/'+product_id)

Tags: django

just need a brief expalanation , i stumbled over this randomly in a Django example, but couldn't find explanation

```
def contact(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    product_id = request.POST['product_id']
    product= request.POST['prodcut']
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
      user_id = request.user.id
      has_contacted = Contact.objects.all().filter(prodcut_id=product_id, user_id=user_id)
    return redirect('/details/'+product_id)
```

i'm just lookin for the signification of using "+" in the redirect, if someone know

Thank you very much

Comment: it's string concatenation if the previous term was a string

Answer (score 3):

It's called **string concatenation**.

If `product_id` is 1, then `redirect` receives `/details/1`

Some more simple examples of this with input & output are;

```
>>> 'a' + 'b' + 'c'
'abc'

>>> 'do' * 2
'dodo'
```

There's a really useful article about it here; https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/#concatenating-and-joining-strings